# Why does Angular recommend to use a FactoryProvider for upgraded ajs services, instead of an InjectionToken?

Tags: angular, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade

In their [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#making-angularjs-dependencies-injectable-to-angular), they use this `FactoryProvider` example for upgrading ajs services:

```
import { HeroesService } from './heroes.service';

export function heroesServiceFactory(i: any) {
  return i.get('heroes');
}

export const heroesServiceProvider = {
  provide: HeroesService,
  useFactory: heroesServiceFactory,
  deps: ['$injector']
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  providers: [
    heroesServiceProvider
  ],
/* . . . */
})
```

Is there any reason to not do it like this with an `InjectionToken` instead, so that way you don't have to add it to the `providers` list for every module that it needs to be used in?

```
import { HeroesService } from './heroes.service';
import {inject, InjectionToken} from '@angular/core';
import {auto} from 'angular';

export const heroesServiceToken = new InjectionToken<HeroesService>('HeroesServices', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory() {
    const $injector = inject('$injector' as any) as auto.IInjectorService;
    const instance = $injector.get('heroes');
    return instance as HeroesService;
  }
});

...
import { HeroesService } from './heroes.service';
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';

class SomeComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(heroesServiceToken) private heroesService: HeroesService) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`InjectionToken` generally don't have a value associated with them. They are handy when you need to make a non-token value injectable (i.e. an `Interface`). I think the option for the factory was added in a later version of Angular, and once it has a factory there is an associated value for the token. Therefore, a token with a factory should not be used in a providers array.

I feel the documentation uses the most common use case, and is easier to people to understand.

> so that way you don't have to add it to the providers list for every module that it needs to be used in?

That statement isn't totally correct.

You add it to the providers in a module **if** that module needs to **provide** it. When a module *needs to use it* the provider is injected, and the value is resolved by finding a parent injector that provides it. Adding a provider to the *root* tends to make it available to everyone.

Getting a provider *into* the *root* can be tricky. So the Angular compiler looks for injections to see if it is being used, and should it find a usage the compiled application will have it added to the `provideIn` declaration. Otherwise, we have to provide it manually.

I say tricky, because source code like `let thing = injector.get(myThing)` isn't picked up by the compiler. Constructor parameters and `@Inject()` are the only things that I'm aware of that the compiler will see.

Using a factory with a token hides the life cycle of that value. Unless someone goes and looks at where the token is declared, then they won't know how it was created. Providing the factory in a module is more common placed and people will see it.

If you need to use `provideIn` with a *factory* then I think the token is the only way.

Comment: I kinda forgot about this question, but anyways, part of the reason I asked this is because  from the point of view of Angular, AngularJS services are singletons, and they are available to be used in any of the Angular modules. So when I was going over some older code in a codebase I'm a part of, I was just thinking that it seemed unnecessary to provide the AngularJS services across multiple modules. The main reason is because `$injector.get('<servicename>')` should be returning the same instance every time anyways. Or is there some situation I'm missing where this won't be the case?

Comment: Also, I just feel like it requires less boilerplate code with the `InjectionToken` as opposed to having to update each module when you decide to start using an AngularJS service there.

Comment: Also, if the upgraded service needs to be injected into a service that is `providedIn: 'root'`, doesn't it also need to be in the root as well, otherwise depending on what module the root service is first used, it may not have the upgraded service available to be injected.